# Javascript and php Round Up decimals

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having values like 7030.56,5875.78,8852.67. I want to round up value when .7 and above come on after decimal point.

Eg

I want round up when coming like this:

```
        (i) 5875.78 -rounded value 5876
        (i) 8978.78 -rounded value 8979
```

I dont want round up when coming like this:

```
        (i) 5875.58 -rounded value 5875.58
        (i) 8978.68 -rounded value 8978.68
```

I want to implement client side and server side also.Php and javascript also.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I used javascript Math.round() ,but its roundup when decimal point .5 and above,I need only .7 and above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you have to implement an own logic.

An example:
$num is your number

PHP:

```
$fraction = $num - floor($num);
if($fraction >= 0.7) {
    $result = ceil($num);
}else{
    $result = $num;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var fraction = num - Math.floor(num);
var result = num;
if(fraction >= 0.7) {
    result = Math.ceil(num);
}
```

Comment: This is more or less a possible working pseudo code. Give it a try.

Comment: var purity_weight=188.7;

var fraction = purity_weight - Math.floor(purity_weight);
var result = purity_weight;
if(fraction > 0.7) {
   result = Math.ceil(purity_weight);
}

when i find math.floor i am getting only 0.699999787 not 7